# Why is JS slice no working while inside the Array.map funciton?

Tags: arrays, slice

As you can run this code snippet my array.slice() seems to not work or I might have messed some other logic. After checking with different approach to extract out the array (using push) the whole code is working fine . But on this approach with slice() it doesn't extract out the copy of "width" array.

What am I missing here?

```js
function serviceLane(cases,width) {
    console.log(cases)

    var b = cases.map((e,i,ar)=>{
        
        var entry = e[0];
        var exit = e[1];
        console.log(entry)
        console.log(exit)

        console.log(width)
       // var p =[];
        var v=exit-entry+1;
       
       var p = width.slice(entry,v)
        console.log(p);


        var m =Math.min(...p)
        console.log(m)
        return m ;

    })

    console.log(b)

    return b;
}

console.log(serviceLane([ [ 0, 3 ], [ 4, 6 ], [ 6, 7 ], [ 3, 5 ], [ 0, 7 ] ],[ 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3 ]))
```

Comment: can you explain the real problem you are trying to solve rather explaining what you think is not working? also when `entry > v` array will be empty and `Math.min()`(`Math.min(...[]) in your case`) with no params return `Infinity`.

Comment: @AZ_ Why is slice()  as in here,  `var p = width.slice(entry,v)`  not working as it prompts empty array at console. You can see in the snippet also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs of `Array.slice([begin, [end]])`

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
> into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included)
> where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The
> original array will not be modified. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

But you are using it like `width.slice(begin, elemsToTake)` Thus for instance, in the second iteration of map, you are doing `width.slice(4,3)` which means, *extract from the array beginning at index 4, ending (not including) at index 3* which results of course in an empty array, because the end index is smaller than the begin.

You probably want to do

```
var p = width.slice(entry, exit +1)
```